# How to delete an JPanel Object?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jpanel, paint

Im on to create a little "game", something like an 2d AirForce Shooter.
So, i have a problem with deleting unused enemys.

An Enemy is an simple JPanel, which is saved in the main logic as an array List.

```
public static ArrayList<Enemy> enemys = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
```

The Enemy run logic does the following:

```
while(!destroyed){
        if(Game.running){
            x--;
            if(getBounds().intersects(Field.player.getBounding())){
                Player.death = true;
            }
            if(x < 0){
                Field.deleteEnemy(this);
            }
            setBounds((int) x, (int) y, 100, 50);
            try{Thread.sleep(10);}catch(InterruptedException e){}
        }
    }
```

So you can seem there i already tried to call the method deleteEnemy, and just give it the unused Enemy.

But it isnt possible - when i just do this:

```
    public static void deleteEnemy(Enemy e){
    System.out.println("test");
    enemys.remove(e);
}
```

It will be just removed from the list, but coninues existing on the Main JPanel.
And i cannot say

```
remove(e);
```

Because then i try to call a non static function in a static. 
So, how could i delete an Enemy? Someone knows?

Thanks for help!

The hole code: (Game.java)

And, Enemy.java:

```
package Game;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Field extends JPanel implements Runnable{


    public static Player player = new Player();
    public static ArrayList<Enemy> enemys = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
    private Thread moveBackground = new Thread(this);
    private boolean bgMoving = false;
    public static boolean addMob = false;
    private int x = 0;
    private int bgSpeed = -1;


    public Field(){
        setBounds(0, 0, 800, 600);
        setFocusable(true);
        setLayout(null);
        addKeyListener(new Handler());

        add(player);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Field.super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(Images.images[0], x, 0, this);
    }

    public static void deleteEnemy(Enemy e){
        System.out.println("test");
        enemys.remove(e);
    }

    public void run(){
        while(!Player.death){
            if(bgMoving){
                bgMoving = true;
                x += bgSpeed;
                if(x < -(Images.images[0].getWidth(this) - this.getWidth() - 20)){
                    bgMoving = false;
                }
                repaint();
                try { Thread.sleep(20); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
            if(addMob){
                enemys.add(new Enemy());
                add(enemys.get(enemys.size() - 1));
                addMob = false;
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DIED!");
    }

    public class Handler extends KeyAdapter {

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            player.KeyPressed(e);
            if(!bgMoving){
                if(Game.running){
                    bgMoving = true;
                    if(moveBackground.getState().toString() == "NEW"){
                        moveBackground.start();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            player.KeyReleased(e);
        }

    }

}
```

And, Enemy.java:

```
package Game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Enemy extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    private double x = Game.width();
    private double y = Math.random() * Game.height();
    private double xF = 0, yF = 0;
    private boolean destroyed = false;

    public Enemy(){
        setBounds((int) x, (int) y, 100, 50);
        setOpaque(false);
        t.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Enemy.super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawImage(Images.images[2], 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void run() {
        while(!destroyed){
            if(Game.running){
                x--;
                if(getBounds().intersects(Field.player.getBounding())){
                    Player.death = true;
                }
                if(x < 0){
                    Field.deleteEnemy(this);
                }
                setBounds((int) x, (int) y, 100, 50);
                try{Thread.sleep(10);}catch(InterruptedException e){}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  *"The hole code:"*  Not only do people typically not want to see the whole code, but that is obviously ***not*** the whole code, since it is not an applet and has no `main(String[])` defined.  Best to post an SSCCE..

Comment: The only static method or field in your entire game should be the main method to get your GUI started.

Answer (score 2):

After removing you will need to call [revalidate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate%28%29) and [repaint()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

[Too long for a comment]

I think the problem is in your logic on removing an `Enemy`/`JPanel`:

You are removing it from the `ArrayList` only, what about the containing `JPanel`/`JFrame` you added it to? 
You must remove the `JPanel` from its container (maybe another `JPanel` or the `JFrame`) not just the `ArrayList` via `Component#remove(Component c)`.

If you drew the Enemy images directly in `paintComponent(...)` of your container via iterating the `ArrayList`; removing it from the `ArrayList` would be sufficient, as it will no longer be in the Array and thus no longer drawn on the next `repaint()`.

+1 to @Optional, you may need to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the container for the affects of the removed `JPanel`/`Enemy` to be shown.

Also as @darijan mentioned, the use of static variables along with instance is not really a great design (though for certain designs this may be fine).

In your case if you need access to an instance method of another class, within another class, simply pass the instance of the class whos method you would like to access to the object which will access it.

Here is some psuedo code expressing much of the above mentioned *problems* / *solutions*:

```
public class Field extends JPanel {
   private ArrayList<Enemy> enemies;

    public Field() {
        ...

        enemies.add(new Enemy(this));//create a new enemy and pas it the JPanel instance so it may access instance methods of this class
    }

    //ONLY USED IF JPanel for Enemy is ommited and Enemy class created which represents Enemy object and not Enemy object and aJPanel
   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

         ArrayList<Enemy> enemiesClone = new ArrayList<>(enemies);//copy array into another so we don't get a ConcurrentModificaton exception if removeEnemy is called while iterating the list
        if(!enemiesClone.isEmpty())
            for(Enemy e:enemiesClone) {//iterate through array of images
                draw(e.getImage(),e.getX(),e.getY(),this);
            } 
   }

    public void removeEnemy(Enemy e) {
        enemies.remove(e);//remove from the array

        //ONLY USED IF JPanels are used as Enemy
        remove(e);//remove from the JPanel
        //so the changes of removed panel can be visible seen
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
}

class Enemy extends JPanel //extends JPanel should be ommited for paintComponent method of drawing an enemy onscreen
{
    private int x,y;
    private BufferedImage image;
    private Field f;

    public Enemy(Field f) {//constructor accepts Field instance to access instance method for the class
        this.f=f;
    }

    public void update() {
        if(offscreen||dead) {
            f.removeEnemy(this);//call removeEnemy which is an instance method of Field
        }
    }

    //BELOW METHODS ONLY USED WHEN Enemy represents object and not a JPanel which can draw its image itself (and update position by simply changing co-ordinates)

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public int getX() {
       return x;
    }
    public int getY() {
       return y;
    }
}
```

For a more detailed look check [Game Development Loop, Logic and Collision detection Java Swing 2D](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/code/444547/game-development-loop-logic-and-collision-detection-java-swing-2d) I made which will give you the basics needed for most 2D games. However I do not use `JPanel`s rather draw directly to a container.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you add an `Enemy` to `JPanel`?

Basically, you should call remove on `Field` `JPanel`:

```
 public void deleteEnemy(Enemy e){
    System.out.println("test");
    enemys.remove(e);
    this.remove(e);
 }
```

The method should not be `static`.

Comment: Taking it that his/her Array is static I cant see this causing problems (not that its a good design). But I dont see what the array is used for, nowhere is the array being iterated and the `JPanel`s used.. so removing it from the array does nothing, I guess OP needs to remove the `JPanel` from its container using `Component#remove(Component c)`